# I am converting a working .NET 4.0 application to .NET 3.5 with string.join

Tags: c#

I am converting a working .NET 4.0 application to .NET 3.5. Please, help me
Here is the code:

```
NameValueCollection qs = new NameValueCollection();
qs["aid"] = "aaa";
qs["fields"] = "1";
qs["aaa"] = "d";

tb.Text = String.Join("&", from item in qs.AllKeys select item + "=" + qs[item]);
```

Answer (score 3):

.NET 3.5 does not contain the

[`String.Join(String, IEnumerable<String>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx)

overload. Thus, you have to use the

[`String.Join(String, String[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

overload. To convert an `IEnumerable<String>` to a string array, use the [`ToArray` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

`String.Join` in .NET 3.5 does not accept `IEnumerable<string>` but it does accept `string[]`.  You can simply add a call to `ToArray` to your LINQ query:

```
NameValueCollection qs = new NameValueCollection();
qs["aid"] = "aaa";
qs["fields"] = "1";
qs["aaa"] = "d";

tb.Text = String.Join("&", (from item in qs.AllKeys select item + "=" + qs[item]).ToArray());
```